# How to validate Antd Form and show only red border without error text?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have this form:
[image]

At the moment validation on submit click looks like this:
[image]

But I need only red border without error text. How can I do that?
I need this:
[image]

Component

```
 <Form onFinish={handleSubmit} onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed} autoComplete='off'>
...
      <td>
        <Form.Item name='tue'>
          <InputNumberStyled style={{ borderRadius: '10px', width: '60px' }} min={0} max={1000} />
        </Form.Item>
      </td>
...
</Form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set the `message` in the `rules` property of an [antd Form.Item](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.Item) to an empty string.

e.g.:

```
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: '',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvpnks) is a working stackblitz.